# Groupby and apply a specific function to certain columns and another function to the rest of the df Pandas

Tags: pandas, group-by, aggregate

I want to group a df with +30 columns applying 'mean' function to mostly of them, but 'count' to specific ones. I was trying:

```
df.groupby('id').agg({'var1':'count',
                       'var2':'count', 
                       'var3':'mean', 
                       'var4':'mean,
                       'var5':'mean'...})
```

And so on for each column. But I'd like to find a some other more efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add if else in `agg`

```
df = df.groupby('id').agg(lambda x : x.count() if x.name in ['var1','var2'] else x.mean())
```

Comment: What if I need to get the first or last value. x.first() does not work

Comment: @Guerra please open a new question for this ~