# Groupby and apply a specific function to certain columns and get first or last values of the df Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Based on the previous post: [Groupby and apply a specific function to certain columns and another function to the rest of the df Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63126154/groupby-and-apply-a-specific-function-to-certain-columns-and-another-function-to)

I want to group a dataframe with a large amount of columns but applying a function (sum, mean, etc. ) to only two columns and to get the first value of the remaining columns. How can I do that? In the quoted post the following code worked, but when i replace "esle x.mean()" by "esle x.first()", it doesnt work anymore.

```
df = df.groupby('id').agg(lambda x : x.count() if x.name in ['var1','var2'] else x.mean())
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `x.iat[0]` to get the first value. [first](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.first.html) does a very different thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `x.iloc[0]` for first value and `x.iloc[-1]` for last value:

```
df = df.groupby('id').agg(lambda x : x.count() if x.name in ['var1','var2'] else x.iloc[0])
```